# GSAP Draggable carousel works improperly

Tags: javascript, loops, carousel, draggable, gsap

Draggable carousel works improperly if I set repeat: -1, when it finishes a lap and I want to drag it, it seems to go crazy.
https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/zYRWmOb

just add:

`const loop = horizontalLoop(boxes, { paused: false, draggable: true, repeat: -1 });`
how i can fix it?

I tried to set the repeat: -1, but I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the code is in codepen link